# How can I send an email to an email address provided in a hidden input field?

Tags: php, forms, email

I've got a simple PHP email form. This is going to be used for multiple people, so in order to make it easier for people, I have a hidden input field in my html form that is basically the "mailTo" email address.

How do I get the email to send the email to the address provided in the hidden input field?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="formholder">
    <form method="post" action="http://www.artofliz.com/hosting/php/process.php">
        <!-- THE CLIENT'S EMAIL TO ADDRESS GOES HERE!!! -->
        <input name="to" type="hidden" value="lroberts@platinumstrategies.com" />

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" type="email" />

        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" type="tel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP handler:

```
<?php
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $from = 'From: noreply@platinumstrategies.com';
    // $to = 'lroberts@platinumstrategies.com';
    $subject = 'Free Guide Download';

    $body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Phone: $phone";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
      /* Anything that goes in here is only performed if the form is submitted */
      if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
      } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
      }
    }
?>
```

http://pastebin.com/cqZP949r - Additionally, I should note that the `'to'` that's commented out works fine. It's what I'm trying to do currently that's broken.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hidden or not, just get it from $_POST

Comment: Don't do this, handle the e-mail address at the server-side (for example in a config file) as you are creating a form that anybody can use to send spam to anybody.

Comment: ^ listen to this guy.

Comment: Quick note. You should probably use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` instead of `if($_POST['submit']){`

Comment: Plus, using a hidden field with an Email address in it, stands at being found by bots. Use `$to="email@example.com";` instead in your handler.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for bringing that to my attention. We just have to use the same PHP process for multiple forms -- can't have multiple php files. That being said, what if I broke it up into two hidden fields "mail" with 'lroberts' -- and then "url" with 'platinumstrategies.com' -- and then concatenate them to a string, and send it that way? Would bots still be able to find it?

Comment: You can just seperate multiple email addresses in the `$to` with commas and/or add `CC:` in the PHP handler. I.e.: `$to="email_1@example.com, email_2@example.com";` See also the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function on `CC` and `BCC` etc.

Comment: Security through obscurity is never a good solution. You should really close this security hole (somebody is bound to find it...) by using for example different config files for your different  forms.

Comment: Alright. I don't want to take any chances, so I'll just go ahead and put it in the php file.